# UISegmentedControl not changing background image when using target-action

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

My segmented control is working fine.. as long as I do not attach a target-action listener to it. However, it is necessary for me to be able to detect its events.

My Code:

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Following", @"Everybody", @"Nearby", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PatuaOne-Regular" size:12.0f];

UIColor *notChosenButtonColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(201.0/255.0f) green:(198.0/255.0f) blue:(191.0/255.0f) alpha:1.0];
UIColor *chosenButtonColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(235.0/255.0f) green:(218.0/255.0f) blue:(102.0/255.0f) alpha:1.0];

NSDictionary *normalAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            font, UITextAttributeFont,
                            notChosenButtonColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                            [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                            nil];
NSDictionary *selectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  font, UITextAttributeFont,
                                  chosenButtonColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                  nil];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:normalAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:selectedAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standard_bt.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standard_bt_h.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 280, 25);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBordered;


[segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"separator.png"]
            forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
              rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                     barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(segmentToggled:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[headerView addSubview:segmentedControl];

- (void)segmentToggled:(UISegmentedControl*)sender
{
    NSInteger index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    NSLog(@"index: %d",index);
    if(index == 0){
        sender.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        [self.feedDescription removeAllObjects];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{[[WebAPI sharedInstance]getFeed:0 max:100 count:5 controller:self];});
        [self.collectionView reloadData];   
    }else if(index == 1){
        sender.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
        [self.feedDescription removeAllObjects];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{[[WebAPI sharedInstance]getFeed:0 max:100 count:5 controller:self];});
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }else if(index == 2){
        sender.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;
        [self.feedDescription removeAllObjects];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{[[WebAPI sharedInstance]getFeed:0 max:100 count:5 controller:self];});
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }


}
```

How can I implement the target action listener above, and still update my UISegmentedControls background images according to:

```
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standard_bt.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standard_bt_h.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
    - (void)segmentToggled:(UISegmentedControl*)sender
            {
            for (int i=0; i<[sender.subviews count]; i++)
                {
                    if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] respondsToSelector:@selector(isSelected)] && [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected])
                    {

                     [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standard_bt_h.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

                    }
                    if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] respondsToSelector:@selector(isSelected)] && ![[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isSelected])
                    {
                    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standard_bt.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


                    }
                }
            }

Hope it Help You
```

Comment: ty, I got *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISegment setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb81af70'

Comment: There you go! 5 stars for you

Comment: Sorry, I cannot combine you method with what i wanted to achieve.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33272/discussion-between-eyeball-and-kirti-mali)